# Sakai Hibernate lazy initialize

Tags: sakai

I'm having some issues building my database. I have this two hbm mappings:

```
<class name="br.unicamp.iel.model.Module" table="readinweb_modules">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="course" class="br.unicamp.iel.model.Course"
            column="course_id" fetch="select" />

    <property name="position" type="integer" />
    <property name="module_grammar" type="text" />
</class>

<class name="br.unicamp.iel.model.Course" table="readinweb_courses">
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="title" length="255" not-null="true" type="string" />

    <property name="idiom" length="255" not-null="true" type="string" />
    <property name="description" type="text" />
    <set name="courseModules" table="readinweb_modules"
            inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
           <key column="id" not-null="true" />
            <one-to-many class="br.unicamp.iel.model.Module" />
    </set>
</class>
```

and when I try to access data on my logic bean as:
List modules = new ArrayList(dao.findById(Course.class,
                course).getCourseModules());

it gives me a
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
a collection of role: br.unicamp.iel.model.Course.courseModules, no
session or session was closed

Answer (score -1):

We need to see the complete code of the

```
List modules = new ArrayList(dao.findById(Course.class, course).getCourseModules())
```

Do you open and close a Session (or a `EntityManager`) inside the `dao.findById` method? The session must still be open to resolve lazy relationships

Comment: You should really ask clarifying questions in the comments, then answer when you have a solution.

Comment: Well, i asked about the code and gave him a hint about the way that lazy load works...